# Lost network interface with Ubuntu server terminal

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04, ifconfig

Trying to run a Minecraft server on Ubuntu. I only have the terminal, no GNOME. Somehow I lost the network. `ifconfig` only shows the loopback.

`/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`
shows:

```
# PCI device 0x8086:0x1050 (e100)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", 
ATTR{address}=="00:0c:f1:85:4f:f2", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", 
KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`
shows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

When I run `sudo ifup eth0`
I get:

```
Cannot find device "eth0"
Error getting hardware address for "eth0": No such device
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rebooting and looking for the interface in the kernel messages?

These are from my notes for CentOS (I realize you said Ubuntu) from a few years ago (but the 70-persistent-net.rules part made me think this may be helpful):

1. Edit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.  Delete the HWADDR line
2. rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
3. Reboot

Reference:  http://joshbolling.com/2012/04/29/force-centos-6-to-re-detect-network-devices/